# Redirect to another page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook, grails

Im developing a webapp for Android and iPhone. I need the "share in facebook" functionality, and i know i can use the url "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=", appending the url to that to open the share in Facebook window we all know and love. Im trying to do it with JavaScript, but the url that is going to be shared must be appended dynamically...

I've tried so far:

```
function goP(){
    var fname=${promo.urlPromocion};
    window.location = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+${object.url};
}
```

With quotes, without quotes, with and without the + symbol between the facebook url and the url to share, even tried to hardcode an url. I don't know if the JS function is even called. But, it doesn't work. Here is the portion of gsp file where the function is called:

```
<div class="rrss" style= "width:60px; height:60px; float:left; margin-right:10px; margin-left:68px;" id="facebook"><a href="JavaScript:goP()"><img src="../images/img_mobile/1340130521_facebook.png"/></a></div>
```

Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to

```
window.location.href = ....
```

Comment: Also make sure you're escaping the data from `${object.url}`

Comment: i think the function is not even called. I tested with window.location.href = 'www.google.com';, but the page doesn't open.

Comment: But, in firefox, if i hover the cursor over the facebook button, it says: "JavaScript:goP" down.

Comment: Don’t _“think”_ or _suppose_ or whatever – __verify__. Put an alert/console.log statement at the begin of your function, look into your browser’s error console, etc. … for short: __debug!__

Comment: Does it need to be an <a> tag?  Could you just stick  onclick="goP()" into the <div> and remove the <a>?  Try putting an alert in the function and/or using firebug to see its called, it could be running into an error, such as invalid syntax due to the value of ${object.url} as tkone hinted.

Comment: Debugged (with an alert()) and the function is called. I deleted the ${} stuff, did what you suggested (with onClick) and now it works, but redirects me to myapp/domainclass/url. I will keep searching. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`window.location.href = 'http://example.com';`

window.location is actually an object that has a property called "href".

Answer (score 0):

```
The following script can help you.

<script type="text/javascript">
        function SubmitFrm() {
            var Searchtxt = $("#<%= txtSearchBooks.ClientID%>").val();
            window.location = "http://www.website.com/search?sUrl=" + Searchtxt;
        }
</script>

For More Details
```

[Click Here](http://aspdotnet41.blogspot.in/2013/09/redirect-to-another-page-using.html)